# Como obter timezone?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
var minhaData = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, meuTimeZone);
```

Caso `meuTimeZone = "E. South America Standard Time";` então o valor retornado para `minhaData` fica com timezone `-03:00`.
É possível de alguma forma obter este valor em horas (neste caso `-03:00`) com base em `meuTimeZone` ou em `minhaData`?

Comment: Não entendi o objetivo, explique melhor.

Comment: Tipo `minhaData.ToString("zzz");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria isto:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var minhaData = DateTime.UtcNow;
        WriteLine($"Hora universal {minhaData.ToLocalTime()}");
        var fuso = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
        var diferenca = new DateTimeOffset(minhaData, TimeSpan.Zero);
        WriteLine($"Hora local {diferenca.ToOffset(fuso.GetUtcOffset(diferenca))}");
        WriteLine($"Diferença {fuso.GetUtcOffset(diferenca)}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xigLkZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYT2AK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/GetTimeZone.cs).